# How do you handle an Ajax.Request call in a Spring MVC (3.0) app?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following call in my JavaScript:

```
new Ajax.Request('/orders/check_first_last/A15Z2W2', 
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, 
parameters:{first:$('input_initial').value, 
last:$('input_final').value, 
order_quantity:$('input_quantity').value}});
```

What do I need to do to get Spring MVC (3.0) to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public OrderController {

   @RequestMapping("/check_first_last/{code}")
   @ResponseBody
   public Result checkFirstLast(@PathVariable String code, 
        @RequestParam int first, 
        @RequestParam int last, 
        @RequestParam("order_quantity") int orderQuantity)  {

       // fetch the result
       Result result = fetchResult(...);
       return result;
  }
}
```

A few notes:

- `@PathVariable` gets a variable defined with `{..}` in the request mapping
- `@RequestParam` is equvallent to `request.getParameter(..)`. When no value is specified, the name of the parameter is assumed (`first`, `last`). Otherwise, the value (`order_quantity)` is obtained from the request.
- `@ResponseBody` means you need Jackson or JAXB present on the classpath, and `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in the xml config. It will render the result with JSON or XML respectively.

If you want to write HTML to the response directly, you have two options:

- change the return type to `String` and return the HTML as a `String` variable
- add an `HttpServletResponse response` parameter to the method and use the `response.getWriter().write(..)` method to write to the response

---

Resource: [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: Brilliant! And if I need to write a response back to the page by replacing some HTML, can I do so from your checkFirstLast() method? Oh wait, is that what you mean by @ResponseBody?

Comment: @Bozho: Wouldn't that call to the write() method result in a brand new HTML page or would it allow me to replace an element on the existing page without a page refresh? I have a text element on the page that I would like to update with a calculation I would perform in the checkFirstLast() method, but without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Bozho: Thanks. I think I'm starting to understand how it works now.

Comment: I'd suggest a quick read of the document that I linked. It is really not so long and sheds light on many important aspects.